# Utilizando modal boxes ¿Cómo esconderlas haciendo click en cualquier parte de la pantalla?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap, web

He estado mirando distintas preguntas y en teoría lo que necesito hacer se consigue como les responden a otros. No obstante, no consigo que funcione como quiero. Intento explicar mi problema.

Tengo una web(usando bootstrap) con una sección digamos. Esa sección la divido en 2 filas, con 2 grupos de columnas de 6 cada uno. Es decir, algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El funcionamiento es el siguiente, de base las modal box están escondidas y aparecen en los sitios que se muestran en la imagen, cuando haces click en los símbolos de +. Cada símbolo te saca información diferente.

El problema que tengo, es que con el script que uso(es un poco a pelo, lo siento):

```js
<script>
  var giiInfo = document.getElementById('GIItext');
  var gmiInfo = document.getElementById('GMItext');
  var mussInfo = document.getElementById('MUSStext');
  
  var emseInfo = document.getElementById('EMSEtext');
  var eitInfo = document.getElementById('EITtext');
  var dgInfo = document.getElementById('DGtext');
  document.onclick = function(event) {
   if (event.target == giiInfo || event.target == gmiInfo || event.target == mussInfo || event.target == emseInfo || event.target == eitInfo || event.target == dgInfo) {
    event.target.style.display = "none";
   }
  }
 </script>
```

Con ese script, solo se me cierra la modal box si doy en el espacio(modal box no incluido) que ocuparian las 6 columnas correspondientes al lugar donde se muestran las modal box, y solo se me cierra la última abierta(segun las abres se superponen una a otra en vez de cerrarse la anterior y abrirse la nueva en el mismo sitio).

Lo que pretendo es que al hacer click en cualquier parte de la web que no sea la modal box, se cierren. Incluso si doy a cualquier + para abrir información nueva.

Espero que no sea muy lioso de entender. Y gracias por adelantado. Un saludo.

**EDIT:**

```html
<div class="row noSideMargin webMargins">
   <div class="col-sm-12">
    <h2>POSTGRADUATE</h2>
   </div>
</div>
 
<div class="row noSideMargin webMargins">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <p class="boldDoc" style="line-height: 2.5;">GII <a style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="document.getElementById('GIItext').style.display='block'" id="giiBtn"><i class="fas fa-plus" style="color:4a4a4a;"></i></a><br>
     GMI <a style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="document.getElementById('GMItext').style.display='block'" id="gmiBtn"><i class="fas fa-plus" style="color:4a4a4a;"></i></a><br>
     MUSS <a style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="document.getElementById('MUSStext').style.display='block'" id="mussBtn"><i class="fas fa-plus" style="color:4a4a4a;"></i></a></p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div id="GIItext" class="modal" style="display:none">
    
     <div class="modal-content">
      <header class="myContainer" style="background-color:#4a4a4a66;"> 
       <span onclick="document.getElementById('GIItext').style.display='none'" class="close">&times;</span>
       <h2 class="grados">GII</h2>
      </header>
      <div class="myContainer">
       <ul class="grados">
        <li>
         <a><h3 class="docencia">Interacción Persona-Ordenador</h3></a>
        </li>
        <li>
         <a><h3 class="docencia">Programación II</h3></a>
        </li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     </div>
     
    </div> 
    
    <div id="GMItext" class="modal" style="display:none">

      <!-- Modal content -->
     <div class="modal-content">
      <header class="myContainer" style="background-color:#4a4a4a66;"> 
       <span onclick="document.getElementById('GMItext').style.display='none'" class="close">&times;</span>
       <h2 class="grados">GMI</h2>
      </header>
      <div class="myContainer">
       <ul class="grados">
        <li class="grados">
         <a><h3 class="docencia">Interacción Persona</h3></a>
        </li>
        <li class="grados">
         <a><h3 class="docencia">Programación II</h3></a>
        </li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     </div>
     
    </div>
    
    <div id="MUSStext" class="modal" style="display:none">

      <!-- Modal content -->
     <div class="modal-content">
      <header class="myContainer" style="background-color:#4a4a4a66;"> 
       <span onclick="document.getElementById('MUSStext').style.display='none'" class="close">&times;</span>
       <h2 class="grados">MUSS</h2>
      </header>
      <div class="myContainer">
       <ul class="grados">
        <li class="grados">
         <a><h3 class="docencia">Interacción Ordenador</h3></a>
        </li>
        <li class="grados">
         <a><h3 class="docencia">Programación II</h3></a>
        </li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
    
    
    
    
    
    
    <script>
  var giiInfo = document.getElementById('GIItext');
  var gmiInfo = document.getElementById('GMItext');
  var mussInfo = document.getElementById('MUSStext');
  
  var emseInfo = document.getElementById('EMSEtext');
  var eitInfo = document.getElementById('EITtext');
  var dgInfo = document.getElementById('DGtext');
  
  /*document.onclick = function(event) {
   if(event.target.id != giiInfo || event.target != gmiInfo || event.target != mussInfo || event.target != emseInfo || event.target != eitInfo || event.target != dgInfo) {
       document.getElementById("GIItext").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("GMItext").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("MUSStext").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("EMSEtext").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("EITtext").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("DGtext").style.display = "none";
   }
  }*/
  
  document.onclick = function(event) {
   if (event.target == giiInfo || event.target == gmiInfo || event.target == mussInfo || event.target == emseInfo || event.target == eitInfo || event.target == dgInfo) {
    document.getElementById("GIItext").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("GMItext").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("MUSStext").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("EMSEtext").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("EITtext").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("DGtext").style.display = "none";
   }
  }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si no he entendido mal, lo que quieres es cerrar los modales haciendo clic en cualquier parte de la ventana ¿no?.

El problema está en tu `if`. Al decirle `event.target == giiInfo` le estás diciendo que funcione si haces click sobre la zona del `giiInfo` (Igual con el resto de los or dentro del if). Si quieres que funcione en general haciendo clic en cualquier punto del documento yo eliminaría eso.

```
document.onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("IdDelModalACerrar").style.display = "none";
}
```

Si quieres que se cierren los dos puedes repetir el `document.getElementById("IdDelModalACerrar").style.display = "none";` y cambiar el id por el del segundo.

Ten en cuenta que al ponerlos los dos juntos cerrarás ambos modales a la vez si están los dos abiertos.

**EDIT:**

Para solucionar el problema de que los modales se cierren antes de abrirse (por así decirlo) debes hacer al contrario a lo que tenías. Es decir, comprobar si se ha hecho click sobre un + y, si es así, no cerrarlo si no abrirlo.

```
document.onclick = function(event) {
   if(event.target.id != document.getElementByID("id1") || event.target.id != document.getElementByID("id2") || etc.) {
       document.getElementById("IdDelModalACerrar").style.display = "none";
   }
}
```

De esta forma no ejecutará el código si se ha hecho click sobre un +, lo que ocurre cuando haces click sobre ellos ya lo defines en otro sitio (si no me equivoco ya lo tienes así que no lo pongo).

Por otra parte, si haces click sobre +1, luego sobre +2, y luego otra vez sobre +1 para que éste aparezca por encima de +2 puedes modificar su z-index.

```
document.getElementById("id1").style.zIndex = "número";
```

Para asegurarte de que lo supere puedes coger el del modal 2 y sumarle uno:

```
var num = document.getElementById("id+2").style.zIndex;

document.getElementById("id1").style.zIndex = num + 1;
```

Comment: Buenos días, gracias por tu respuesta, he probado lo que dices.

El problema que veo con ello(ya me pasó anteriormente) es que entonces al dar a los + no se abre la información. Es como si la ocultase instantáneamente antes de abrirla. O al menos eso es lo que creo que pasa.

Así mismo el otro problema que tenía, es que si abro el 1er +, luego el 2º(este se abre sobre el primero) y si vuelvo a darle al 1er + no se abre porque ya está abierto(debajo del 2o texto).

Comment: En ese caso debes hacer lo contrario a lo que tenías para solucionar lo de que se cierre nada más abrirse. Y para abrir uno ya abierto puedes hacerlo modificando su z-index, edito la respuesta con todo bien explicado

Comment: Buenos días de nuevo. Siento decir que con esa solución siguen sin mostrarse las modal boxes con la información cuando doy a un +.

Mi código para hacer click en los + sigue el siguiente formato:

<a style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="document.getElementById('EMSEtext').style.display='block'" id="emseBtn"><i class="fas fa-plus" style="color:4a4a4a;"></i></a>

Llevo tiempo peleándome con esto y alguna otra cosa así que perdona si estoy un poco espeso.

Comment: ¿Podrías editar tu pregunta con el html y js más completo para poder verlo bien? Es confuso intentar ayudarte cuando no sé cómo llamas a las cosas y demás... (Me estoy liando yo sola intentando resolverlo)

Comment: Vale, tienes toda la razón, perdona. He editado y copiado el primer fragmento correspondiente a los 3 primeros +. Y el script que uso en el propio html, el cual tendría que modificar.
Perdona la indentación que la pone como quiere al pegarlo. No copio todo el código que son unas 700 líneas. El css tampoco lo adjunto que son otras tantas y bastante más lioso.
Gracias por toda tu ayuda. Un saludo.

Comment: Buenos días de nuevo, quería simplemente informar de que al final se ha decidido por hacer esa parte de la web de una forma distinta. Por lo que no es necesario que sigas intentando ayudarme. Muchas gracias por toda tu ayuda, un saludo.